# How to get the pid of the other side of pipe?

Tags: linux, perl, bsd

I want to know pid of the other side of the pipe. If Linux, I can match up the id of `ls -l /proc/SELF_PID/fd/0` like these commands.

```
[root@host ~]# command1 | command2 &

I've known command2's PID = 5912.

[root@host ~]# ls -l /proc/5912/fd/0 
lr-x------  1 root root 64 Mar 25 18:00 /proc/5912/fd/0 -> pipe:[540748072]
[root@host ~]# ls -l /proc/[0-9]*/fd/1 | grep 'pipe:\[540748072\]'
l-wx------  1 root root 64 Mar 25 18:01 /proc/5911/fd/1 -> pipe:[540748072]
[root@host ~]# cat /proc/5911/cmdline 
vmstat12
```

Are there better ways on Linux? or How to get on BSD and the other OS?

And I want to know if there is a good CPAN module...

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to know who is listening on the pipe ?

Comment: I want to name the log file using the command name of the other side of the stdin pipe.

Comment: But what if I do `tee_log <some_file | command` ? There is no way to turn a filedescriptor back into a filename (since, for example, a file might be reached through several paths and names thanks to hard- and symlinks).

Comment: I see. But I want to set the logfile name automatically.. Or I want to know the better way for this issue(getting pid of the other side of the pipe) for future reference :)  (There may be a probrem that the pipe is opened from more than 2 processes..)

Comment: I'd just let the user pass a filename (or pattern) as argument, as with the normal `tee` command.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. Is it safer?

Comment: Define "safer" in this context. It certainly is easier ;-)

Comment: yes, I see it's easier. Only I'm too lazy to give the logfile name X-(  Then, to simply ask the topic that how to get the fd information other than Linux, I modified the question.

Comment: Hmm... a pipe is basically for communication between two unrelated processes. And it works by no magic. We have to transfer data between the two processes which needs to communicate using any data structure which can do the job of the pipe(serial data passing) ...AND IT IS ONE WAY COMMUNICATION... so you cannot have the pid of listening process available to the sending process.. A better way would be to use two FIFO's one for writing an done for receiving

Answer (score 0):

In Perl a process can get its own PID with the special variable $$

If you have a pair of pipes, or a socket, each process could just send its own PID into the pipe or socket to be read by the other process.

Also, parents know the PIDs of their children usually through the system call creating them.