# can program know return value of previous command in pipe chain?

Tags: command-line, pipe

If I have `progA | progB`, then can I make some progB executable (in any language) which will know the return code of `progA`?

EDIT:

if the answer is platform dependent, then I would like to know the answers for all platforms since this is a question out of sheer curiousity. However, POSIX machines (linux in particular) are what I use most.

Comment: I'd say not portably. Are we talking about Linux? POSIX? Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is no for POSIX. The two main arguments against it are:

- there is no POSIX way for `progB` to determine the PID of the `progA` process on the other side of the pipe (although there are system-dependent ways around this - on Linux, you can use the pipe's inode number to find the process keeping the other end open in most cases, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430478/how-to-get-the-pid-of-the-other-side-of-pipe) will get you started).
- even if `progB` had the PID of `progA`, it could not receive its exit status since only the parent process of `progA` (in this case probably your shell) can `wait` for it. As far as I can tell, there is no way around this restriction.